# Juno Failed to Fetch Updates - Missing Release file

Tags: updates, apt

I've just installed elementary OS Juno, but I'm getting into trouble when I try to get updates, both via AppCenter or terminal. It seems it cannot fetch updates since it cannot find Release file in the below repositories:
[image]

Is there a way to fix this issue or change to correct repositiories?

Comment: I installed Juno just yesterday; had the same porblem. Would there be an oficial explanation, or solution to this issue? Replacing Juno with Bionic, will still keep the system updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking every repository online, I fixed the issue by replacing `juno` with `bionic` in the below files:

`/etc/apt/sources.list 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list`

Still, have no clue why the repository addresses were wrong.