# Repository problems, on a new installed Juno

Tags: appcenter, release-juno, apt, repositories

After a brand new installation of Elementaty Juno (I come from Linux Mint) I got errors like this one, when updating the system:

```
El repositorio «http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter juno Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
```

Translation is `The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter juno Release' does not have a Release file.`

I had to deactivate Juno repositories and only left "bionic", as recommended here
[Juno Failed to Fetch Updates - Missing Release file](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16888/juno-failed-to-fetch-updates-missing-release-file/16910#16910)

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Change in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list

```
http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter juno main
```

to

```
http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main
```

(juno -> bionic)

---

From https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16889/14940

> After checking every repository online, I fixed the issue by replacing juno with bionic in the below files:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list
```

Comment: I checked these files, and several of them have a single line, with a comment "#" prefix on the line. For example, here are the contents of "patches.list"

Comment: Every line with a # in front is a disabled line or acting as a comment. Edit you own post and add the file content to see what you need.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm a little confused about your answer. The first sentence says to replace only in the `appcenter.list` file, but the list at the bottom mentions four files. Are all four files to be changed? Is the first one special in some way?